# Android SearchManager: How to set minimum number of characters to enable the Search

Tags: android, android-searchmanager

I am using the Android SearchManager. I defined all the needed attributes in the searchable.xml.

Now, I would like to set a limit for minimum numer of characters before the user can make the search. By default, the min is 1.

How can this be changed?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its the following attribute in searchable.xml

```
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  ...
  android:searchSuggestThreshold="2"
  >
</searchable>
```

Answer (score 4):

if onQueryTextSubmit return false then only search action is performing , we can limit chars like this

```
    @Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_home, menu);

        // Get the SearchView and set the searchable configuration
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).getActionView();
        // Assumes current activity is the searchable activity
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getActivity().getComponentName()));
        //searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false); // Do not iconify the widget; expand it by default

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return query.length()<4; //number of char to limit
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                return false;
            }
        });

    }
```